# I get a an extra and diffrent character when using printf for character array

Tags: c

When I run this program and give laks as input I get laks as output plus one extra character.Also if I want to break the program as soon as a new line is entered i.e when I press enter I want the loop to discontinue but while statement does not seem to work.

```html
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <ctype.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();

char person[5];
int i;
printf("enter person name \n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
scanf("%c",&person[i]);
//while(person[i]!='/n')

}
printf("%s",person);

getch();
}
```

Comment: Note that it is `'\n'` and not `'/n'` that is a newline.  Since that's in a comment, it isn't a part of your current problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use `if (scanf("%4s", person) != 1) return 1;` in place of the loop?

Comment: yes I noticed that only after posting.

Comment: @ GOPI In the same program if I want to break the loop by using a while statement  as shown in the program. i.e After pressing enter the systems stucks up.I mean if I type ab and press enter the cursor  does not move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not null terminating your string

So have

```
person[i] = '\0';
```

after the for loop.

I would have

```
char person[6] = "";
```

and later do a scan

Answer (score 1):

Increase the size of the array by 1 and `nul` terminate it:

```
char person[6];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    scanf("%c",&person[i]);    
}
person[i] = '\0'; // or person[i] = 0;
```

If the array is not `nul` terminated `printf` will not understand the end of string. The length of a C string is found by searching for the (first) NUL byte.

To make things simpler you could simply do:

```
char person[6] = { 0 };
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    scanf("%c",&person[i]);    
}
```

Also note `conio.h` is non-standard and the standard mandates `main` method to return an `int`.